# Instantiation of ALAssetsLibrary inside block throws bad access

Tags: cocoa-touch, avfoundation, alassetslibrary, image-capture

I converted my project to arc and now, it throws a bad access error when I instantiate a new assets library. Before ARC there was no problem.

Any suggestions?

```
[self.stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:stillImageConnection
                                                   completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) 
{
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Take picture failed");
    }
    else 
    {
        NSData *jpegData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
        CFDictionaryRef attachments = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(kCFAllocatorDefault, 
                                                                    imageDataSampleBuffer, 
                                                                    kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate);
        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [library writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:jpegData 
                                         metadata:(__bridge_transfer id)attachments
                                  completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
                                      if (error) {
                                          NSLog(@"Save to camera roll failed");
                                      }
                                  }];

        if (attachments)
            CFRelease(attachments);
    }
}];
```

Comment: Sometimes life can be so hard.

Before ARC I didn't had to retain the CFDictionaryRef.

So adding `CFRetain(attachments);` after initializing the attachments removed the bad access.


Cheers,

Comment: Please put your solution in an answer instead of a comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes life can be so hard. Before ARC I didn't had to retain the CFDictionaryRef. So adding CFRetain(attachments); after initializing the attachments removed the bad access.

Cheers,
tubtub

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware, that you should only initialize assetlibrary only one time during the whole life cycle of the application. So you should e.g. Do that in the appdelegate or another singleton. Your code seems to have the risk hat assetslibrary gets initilazed multiple times.

Cheers,

Hendrik